# How can I set Firefox settings with a bash scipt?

Tags: firefox, scripts

I would like to create a bash script that I can run on several computers that will set some basic preferences and bookmarks for Firefox (and possibly Google Chrome) on Ubuntu 12.04. I think user data is stored in `~/.mozilla/firefox/` but I don't know exactly how I would set preferences on a fresh install. Does anyone have an insight on this?

Specifically, I'd like to be able to create a bash script that...

1. Sets bookmarks
2. Sets the bookmarks toolbar to always show
3. Sets the cache to be emptied when the browser closes
4. Turn off remembering passwords

Comment: wouldn't a .desktop file with quicklist and options be an option?

Comment: Not that I know of, Jacob. I just want to ad some lines of code to a bash script that will set some settings and bookmarks when run once.

Comment: You can see all the command line options by typing `firefox --help` (same as most programs).  But the only thing I can think of is setting up a profile (`firefox --ProfileManager`, and using that profile for a new install.

Comment: See [Profiles - Where Firefox stores your bookmarks, passwords and other user data](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data). Those settings are spread on deferent files within profile: Bookmarks in `places.sqlite`. Show bookmarks toolbar in `localstore.rdf`. Seems it needs kind of complex script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a clean profile for that once, then put it on github or whatever, and write a bash script which would delete local `~/.mozilla` and download Your pre-configured one.

Comment: That is what I have done! Thank you for the idea! I am hosting my files on Dropbox, downloading with wget, and then unzipping to replace current profile. Genius!

Comment: I am able to do the same thing with Google Chrome by backing up and replacing the .config/google-chrome/Default folder and its contents.